# What are the Express.js equivalent of Rails Gems?

Tags: node.js, express

Is there some kind of equivalent of Rails "Gems" for express.js? Specifically I'm fishing around for something that can read in RSS feeds efficiently, including the ability to accept poorly formed XML files, but my real question is: where do I even get started looking? (or is Express.js too young to have an extension library?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A lot of people compare express to ROR, but should, as the author also does compare it to sinatra instead of ROR.

> Sinatra is a DSL for quickly creating
>   web applications in Ruby with minimal
>   effort

If you haven't already installed [npm](http://npmjs.org)(probably have to install express?) you should. I think you can compare `npm` to `gem`. When searching for `rss` via http://search.npmjs.org I found the following package which could be useful:

- http://search.npmjs.org/#/easyrss

Comment: p.s: I am no ruby master, but I believe that gems have nothing to do with ROR? You can install gems without installing ROR?

Answer (score 1):

Where to start looking:

1. http://search.npmjs.org/   rss
2. https://github.com/   node rss
3. http://google.com  node.js rss

Answer (score 1):

Express.js has modules that can act as middleware to express/connect. Modules such as [everyauth](https://github.com/bnoguchi/everyauth) and [session](http://senchalabs.github.com/connect/middleware-session.html) (which is already bundled with connect) add additional functionality to Express and Connect. Express is built on top of Connect.

[Several great modules already included into Connect](http://senchalabs.github.com/connect/)

[A quick primer on how Express uses middleware.](http://expressjs.com/guide.html#middleware)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about Express specifically, but I know about Node.js `npm` command that lets you install Node packages.

Answer (score 0):

Alfred's answer is very good, I just want to point out that you shouldn't think of "Express Gems" just like you shouldn't think of "Rails Gems", but instead think of "Node.js Gems" and "Ruby Gems".

You can compare Ruby with Node (as they are both languages), Sinatra (and perhaps Rails, but not 100%) with Express.js.

So there are packages for Node.js which you can install with [npm](http://npmjs.org). Express.js is such a package ("gem"). For more packages [search npm](http://search.npmjs.org/)

If you are interested in Express.js middleware, look here on the [Express wiki page](https://github.com/visionmedia/express/wiki)

Comment: Even comparing Ruby with Node.js isn't quite right, JavaScript is the language.  But thinking of NPM modules like Node.js Gems is exactly right.